# Google App Engine Datastore query returning stale data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, model, google-cloud-datastore

I have a project based on GAE using the `db` `Datastore`. In my project I run a job every 15 minutes, and update the data in `Datastore`. Then I have an endpoint that queries the `Datastore` and displays the result. But, the result that I get is stale and not the one that was updated. It seems that GAE doesn't hit the `Datastore` and returns the data from the cache, but I am not sure. Here is my code:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        query = Contests.all()
        contests_data = query.fetch(1) # fetch the data from datastore
        self.response.write(contests_data[0].data)

class DataBaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    # the job that runs every 15 minutes
    def get(self):
        contests_data = get_all_contests() # get the new data
        query = Contests.all()
        contests = query.fetch(1)
        contests[1].data = contests_data # update the data
        db.put(contests[0])
        self.response.write(json.dumps({"message":"updated"}))
```

Here is my model:

```
class Contests(db.Model):
    """Models Contests"""
    data = db.TextProperty(default="{}")
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

I tried clearing the cache using `memcache.flush_all()` but even that doesn't solve the problem. Why doesn't GAE return the updated data? And how do I solve the problem?

**EDIT**: I changed the query to ancestor query but the data is still stale(and it is days old).

`main.py`

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

        def get(self):
            contest_list = ContestList.get_or_insert('contest_list', name='ContestList')
            query = Contests.all()
            query.ancestor(contest_list) 
            contests = query.fetch(1)
            self.response.write(contests[0].data)

    class DataBaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

        def get(self):
            contests_data = get_all_contests()
            contest_list = ContestList.get_or_insert('contest_list', name='ContestList')
            query = Contests.all()
            query.ancestor(contest_list)
            contests = query.fetch(1)
            contests[0].data = contests_data
            contests[0].put()
            self.response.write(json.dumps({"message":"updated"}))
```

`models.py`:

```
class ContestList(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Contests(db.Model):
    """Models Contests"""
    data = db.TextProperty(default="{}")
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

**I even tried getting data by using `key`**:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        q = ndb.Key('Contests', 'contest_data').get()
        if q:
            self.response.write(q.data)
        else:
            self.response.write("error")

class DataBaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        Contests(key=ndb.Key('Contests', "contest_data"), data=get_all_contests()).put()
        self.response.write(json.dumps({"message":"updated"}))
```

What doesn't GAE hit the datastore? What am I missing here?

Comment: Patrice's answer is correct -- and old crufty `db` doesn't transparently do caching for you anyway, you need shiny new great `ndb` for that (controllable of course, by using custom contexts), so problems seen with `db` can't be due to caching, must relate to eventual-consistency,

Comment: Eventual consistency takes 1-2 seconds to resolve itself. If your data is "stale" beyond that, there is a problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, a second or often even less is *typical*, but there's no guaranteed upper bound to the worst-case delay.  Users of modern subsystems such as `ndb` which transparently cache entities hardly ever observe that because memcache **is** strongly consistent (although volatile) -- but it's more prominent with old crufty `db` and anyway "hardly ever" is quite the same thing as "never":-)...

Comment: Your comments are confusing: NDB doesn't cache queries, so would make zero difference in this situation.

Comment: @Greg actually the whole point of NDB is to cache your results into memcache and go there before checking the datastore...

Comment: @Alex - This is not a question of guarantees. If an OP sees stale data after more than a few seconds *every time he tries*, this is definitely not an eventual consistency issue. If the stale data is returned *immediately* after an update is done, then eventual consistency issue would be my first suspect as well.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I see stale data even after hours. I've editted the question for more details.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin given the OP's latest comments and edits you're definitely right.

Comment: @ArchitVerma. That is definitely something weird..... Can you confirm from the datastore viewer in your admin console that data is actually updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datastore is only eventually consistent for queries. There is a possiblity, during replication of your data, that you hit "stale" data, indeed.

To make sure you force strong consistency in a query, you need to use an ancestor query, or a get by key.

Read more about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/)

## Ex: ancestor query

([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Ancestor_queries)) To do that, you would obviously need to change your structure a bit. I don't know what could be the ancestor of the model "Contest", but let's say they all fall under a "mainAncestor" entity.

When you create your entities, you'll need to have something akin to :

```
newContest = Contest(parent=mainAncestor)
```

Then when you retrieve, you add this in your code :

```
query = Contests.all()
query.ancestor(mainAncestor) 
contests = query.fetch(1)
```

That will force strong consistency accross your data. You will obviously need to create that "mainAncestor", and it will then cause other caveats you'll need to make sure you address (you can only write to an entity group (entities grouped under the same ancestor) once every second, for instance).

Comment: Good answer but to make it great I have 2 suggestions: (A) you could also link directly to https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/ (no need to send the OP through that Java-focused SO Q:-) and (B) ideally also offer a simple Python example of how to artificially use an ancestor query in the OP's use case... I upvoted anyway, but recommend you enrich the answer!-)

Comment: Fair point. for A), that was actually the link I intended to use. I should've double-checked. I will correct that and add B shortly :). Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @Patrice @AlexMartelli Thanks a lot for your help! But even after adding ancestor query and trying to get data by `key`, it doesn't work. I've editted the question for more details.